# Printing strings using PrintWriter

Tags: java

### Facing problem while trying to print using PrintWriter.

**Problem Description:**

> I am expecting to print the `Press` options first then take the user input but using `out.println` i can't do that. It's not printing the options while i run the program. It just waits for an input while i give the input it then prints the Press options.

**Note:** *if i use `System.out.println` then it works as expected.*

**Tried it like below**

```
public class Calculator {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        PrintWriter out =  new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
        StringTokenizer took = new StringTokenizer(" ");
        String operator;
//            System.out.println("Press '+' for Additon");
//            System.out.println("Press '-' for Subtraction");
//            System.out.println("Press '*' for multiplication");
        out.println("Press '+' for Additon");
        out.println("Press '-' for Subtraction");
        out.println("Press '*' for multiplication");
        out.println("Press '/' for Division");

        operator=in.readLine();
        switch (operator) {
            case "+":
                out.println("Add");
                break;
            case "-":
                out.println("Subtract");
                break;
            case "*":
                out.println("Multiply");;
                break;
            case "/":
                out.println("Division");
                break;
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
    }
}
```

**Input:**

```
*
```

**Output:**

```
Press '+' for Additon
Press '-' for Subtraction
Press '*' for multiplication
Press '/' for Division

Multiply
```

Comment: Flush, flush, flush! Or `autoFlush`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do:

```
out.flush();
```

Before you read in, and then before you close the `out`.

Or you can do:

```
PrintWriter out =  new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out), true);
```

What the `true` does is sets it to auto flush every time you print.

Suggest reviewing the Javadoc for the [`PrintWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html).